# Why the Ginzburg-Landau free energy does not have divergence and curl of the order parameter?

Tags: statistical-mechanics, phase-transition

For a vector order parameter $\vec{m}(\vec r)$, Ginzburg-Landau free energy functional contains $|\nabla m|^2$ term, where $m=|\vec m(\vec r)|$ but it does not include terms like $\nabla\cdot{\vec m}$ and $|\nabla\times\vec{m}|$. Why?

Comment: In all examples I've seen, the internal space, where $\vec{m}$ transforms as a vector, is not the physical space $\mathbb{R}^3$. If it were, getting a VEV would be strange since it would mean there's a spontaneous breaking of rotational symmetry.

Comment: @ConnorBehan In condensed matter physics, we do have vector-valued order parameters, for example, in paramagnetic to ferromagnetic transition below the Curie point, the order parameter is the magnetization $\vec{m}(\vec r)$.

Comment: Heisenberg magnets are not a counter-example. You can make them very flat until there is only a 2D lattice one atom think. And yet they will still carry $O(3)$ spin.

Comment: I don't understand the point here. Magnets do break O(3) rotational symmetry in $\mathbb{R}^3$. The ground state is not invariant under rotation but the Heisenberg Hamiltonian is.

Comment: Yes. And the temptation to think it's the same $O(3)$ can be overcome if you consider Heisenberg magnets in 2D, XY magnets in 3D, etc.

Comment: Yes I agree with @connorBehan one argument is that other terms would break rotational symmetry *explicitly* (that wouldn't be called spontaneous symmetry breaking), meaning that the action would not be rotational invariant even without the presence of an external magnetic field. But at this semi-, macroscopic level matter is isotropic. The rest of the argument why we don't include higher derivatives involves the renormalization group.

Comment: I think both of the above comments are incorrect. It's true that the target space of your field need not be physical space, but that's no reason you can't consider the curl and divergence of a field if the dimensions match. As a simple example, just look at the action of the magnetic vector potential! These terms also clearly do not break rotational invariance so long as your vector field transforms correctly under rotations. Finally, these sort of terms are not higher derivative terms, they're the same order as the usual gradient term.

Comment: Sure you can have squared divergence in the free energy. This is what happens e.g. in elastic solids. There your $\vec m$ is the displacement vector. Its divergence measures bulk compression of the solid, and a term proportional to $(\vec\nabla\cdot\vec m)^2$ appears in the free energy together with the bulk modulus $K$. In other physical systems, the presence of such a term may be limited by symmetries, as pointed out in the other comments.

Comment: @TomášBrauner I want to know what (symmetry) stops us from having $(\vec{\nabla}\cdot{\vec m})^2$ in the theory of magnetic transition?

Comment: As I said below yyy's answer, it's rotational symmetry in physical space. This is different from rotational symmetry in target space.

Comment: @Solidification You should then adjust your question, since it does not say anything about magnetism. As Connor Behan points out, magnetization is not necessarily a vector under spatial SO(3) rotations. In fact, in the nonrelativistic limit, the spin SU(2) symmetry is independent from spatial rotations. This is what forbids the $(\vec\nabla\cdot\vec m)^2$ term in the free energy. That said, relativistic corrections (spin-orbit coupling) lock the spatial and spin rotations together. So in the end, $(\vec\nabla\cdot\vec m)^2$ might be allowed but can be expected to be very small.

Answer (score 3):

I think that in GL theory we want to construct a general action for the order parameter, that respects microscopic symmetries, and then examine how phase transitions and spontaneous symmetry breakings occur. A very important symmetry that we don't want to *explicitly* break (usually) is $\vec{m} \to -\vec{m}$, exactly because we want to observe how the magnetizations gets non-zero values and this symmetry spontaneously breaks during phase transition. When we do break this symmetry is by a magnetic field term $\vec{B} \cdot \vec{m}$. So all terms linear in $\vec{m}$ are in general not used.

Terms with absolute value such as $|\nabla \times \vec{m}|$ are also frowned upon, as they are "non-local". This is because it is really $\sqrt{\nabla \times \vec{m} \cdot \nabla \times \vec{m}}$ which is not analytical and contains all orders of the derivatives of $\vec{m}$ when doing power expansion.

This leaves us with one last term that we need to consider, and this is $(\nabla \times \vec{m})^2$. However,
$$(\nabla \times \vec{m})^2 = \epsilon_{ijk}\epsilon_{isr}(\partial_j m_k) (\partial_s m_r) = (\delta_{js}\delta_{kr}-\delta_{jr}\delta_{ks})(\partial_j m_k) (\partial_s m_r) = (\partial_j m_k)^2 - (\partial_j m_k)(\partial_k m_j) $$
but all of this is under an integral, and now by using integration by parts* the second term is just
$$ \int d^2r (\partial_j m_k)(\partial_k m_j) = \int d^2r \partial_k m_k \partial_j m_j = \int d^2r (\nabla \cdot \vec{m})^2$$
and the first term is simply $\nabla ^2 \vec{m}^2$, which under an integral gives a boundary term, which we throw out*.

* here we assume that the boundary terms are zero, which is not necessarily the case in topologically non-trivial theories!

Comment: Thanks, @yyy , you did not explain why we do not consider the term $\nabla\cdot{\vec m}$. Also $\nabla^2{\vec m}^2$ is not same as $|\nabla{\vec m}|^2$.

Comment: the term $\nabla \cdot \vec{m}$ breaks the symmetry $\vec{m} \to -\vec{m}$ that we usually require. Re: the term $\nabla ^2 \vec{m}^2$ I thought I explained why we can omit it but now I see that I forgot to put it in my answer. will put it now :)

Comment: Tomas has given the most correct answer so far. For $\nabla \cdot m$ to be allowed, the order parameter needs to be a vector under the rotational symmetry of physical space. But this symmetry only emerges in the continuum limit whereas all ferromagnetic examples are concerned with studying the spontaneous breaking of a symmetry which is preserved by the Hamiltonian for any lattice spacing.

Answer (score 0):

Superfluid helim 3 has a quite a complicated Landau-Gizburg free energy functional
and there is  a nice discussion of some of these issues in Mike Cross's  *A generalized Ginzburg-Landau approach to the superfluidity of helium 3* Journal of Low Temperature Physics volume 21, pages 525–534 (1975).  Terms that are total divergences can still
contribute to the currents.

Comment: thank you! if terms that are total divergences contribute does it mean that the theory topologically non-trivial?